# How to find popup box code in hr module in openerp?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I am new to openerp. Here I need to find out the Bank Account info in HR source code. Please see the popup box in attached image. How to find py files and xml files for Bank Account info. Please any one help me thanks...[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python file for the displayed window is server>openerp>addons>base>res>res_bank.py and the xml file is in the same directory server>openerp>addons>base>res>res_bank_view.xml.

To check where these files are lying , Click on the logged in user at top-right corner of the page. In your case , its Administrator. Then click on About OpenERP. A popup window will be displayed. In this box, click on 'Activate the developer mode' at right side. It will enable a debug mode of OpenERP. Now take a pointer on any field on the page you want to know about. See an example here : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qAbyu1lRemoe_YS1xQObaAkmiBshqrne4cB2bSfuWp0/edit?usp=sharing

Here you can see a small black-box displaying some information. In that box , you can see object. In your case , its 'res.partner.bank'. You can search for this string in text editors like eclipse or software like searchmonkey in files having *.py extension. The file where you find result like _name = "res.partner.bank" is the python file you are searching for. And in the same directory, there will be a file matching the name of py file like res_bank_view.xml. This is the view file.

Hope this will help you. Regards.

Comment: Hi @Dharmraj as you said DEBUG mode is for frontend view change or also for backend change like database interaction.

Comment: Hello dhana, DEBUG mode is only for the front end. It is used to provide the user with more information. Database interaction mechanism remains same in both the DEBUG and regular mode.